# same font and bold for thesis in chapter, section and so on

Tags: thesis

I would like to create the format below for my thesis using `\documentclass{thesis}`

> Introduction   --> no number for chapter
>
> 1. Section
>
> 1.1. Subsection

all of them using same font with text and bold. Please help me as I am beginner for LaTeX and I dont have much time to find the answer.

Comment: Templates called `thesis.cls` are ubiquitous: where can we have a look to the one you're using?

Comment: I use thesis template from http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis